# PHP Oracle Date Error ORA-01847

Tags: php, oracle, insert

I have some trouble about inserting new record to oracle from php. If I remove date column or change date column format to string i can add new records.

I make some research and try to change date format to diffent types but it didn't work.

I added my oracle table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmYSA.jpg

And this my date format which i try to add as new record.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJUs6.jpg

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID,MYDATECOLE) '.  'VALUES(:ID,:MYDATECOLE,:MYDATECOLE)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
to_date(:MYDATECOLE,'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: to_date transform your date, in your format to oracle format by rule in second parameter

Comment: i try it and gave me this Parse error: sytax error unexpected ‘YYYY’ (T_STRING) error

Comment: I think you need escape quote. I don`t know php, but maybe something like this to_date(:MYDATECOLE,\'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS\')

Comment: thanks for help this time inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE gave this error

Comment: $sql = 'INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID,MYDATE,)'. 'VALUES(:ID,to_date(:MYDATE,\'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS\'))';

Comment: Maybe you really have NUMBER datatype? And what is it INTO MYTABLE(ID,MYDATE**,**)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What type of 'MYDATE' column?